# setsid: can't execute './test.sh': Exec format error

Tags: bash

I tried to execute `setsid ./test.sh` command on Alpine OS in a docker container.

And it says 'Exec format error'. then I  added a header bang '
#!/usr/bin/env bash' to that script. It works.

But the same command and script without header on centos6 works well.

I've digged into it deeply. Seems that setsid is a system call which use execvp to execute command, execvp will treat the script as an execute file.

My script.sh has execute permission and can run with './script.sh'. Why does the script behave differently on alpine and centos?

Comment: I would assume that alpine doesn't know that your script is a executable (it is just a text file after all). bash is the executable that runs the script - so your bang solves it, or you could run it like this: setsid bash test.sh. CentOs might be a bit more clever and knows what you want to do

Comment: Note that while it may work on Centos, you don't really know if `bash` is really the shell being run (in this case, it was most likely run by `/bin/sh` instead). Adding a shebang is considered best practice as this explicitely states which program should run your script